# What does the "#" in this Verilog module instantiation mean?

Tags: verilog

I saw the following instantiation in a Verilog testbench:

```
`define width 8 

    ......

scale_mux #(`width) m1 (.out(out), .sel(sel), .b(b), .a(a));
```

I don't know what the "#" means here. Does it replace the parameter declared in scale_mux  module with the parameter "width" in test bench?
Or does it mean instantiating the scale_mux module 8 times?

The description of scale_mux is  as follows:

```
module scale_mux (out, sel, b, a); 
parameter size = 1; 

output [size-1:0] out; 
input [size-1:0] b, a; 
input sel; 

assign out = (!sel) ? a : 
             (sel)  ? b : 
             {size{1'bx}}; 

endmodule
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, after some searching, I found a possible explanation:

When we want to instantiate a Verilog module with parameter, like this:

```
module scale_mux (out, sel, b, a); 
parameter size = 1; 

output [size-1:0] out; 
input [size-1:0] b, a; 
input sel; 

assign out = (!sel) ? a : 
                           (sel)  ? b : 
                           {size{1'bx}}; 

endmodule
```

The parameter here is `size = 1`.

Instantiating this module like this:

```
scale_mux #(`width) m1 (.out(out), .sel(sel), .b(b), .a(a));
```

is equivalent to

```
scale_mux #(.size(8)) m1 (.out(out), .sel(sel), .b(b), .a(a));
```

So it is to override the parameter, not copying the referred module 8 times.

**REFERENCE:**

1.https://fpgatutorial.com/verilog-generate/